# Symfony3 FOSuserbundle register form one to one entity

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

i neeed in my symfony base aplication 4 types of user,one of them is super user and can be just typical fosuserbundle user, but need to admin can add 3 different type of user. So i do a new Client class for one type of user which has 1:1 entity with my base user class

```
class Client{
my client class fields
...
   /**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $user;
...
}
```

And my User class

```
class User extends BaseUser
{......}
```

The Question is how to do a register form for this ? Please help me

Now i have this UserType form

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
   }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
          'data_class' => User::class,
       ));
   }

   public function getParent()
   {
       return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
   }

   public function getBlockPrefix()
   {
       return 'app_user_registration';
   }
}
```

And my clientForm class

```
class ClientForm extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder
           ->add('name', TextType::class)
           ->add('address', TextareaType::class)
           ->add('phone', TextType::class)
           ->add('deliveryAddress', TextareaType::class)
           ->add('user', UserType::class);
   }

   public function getParent()
   {
       return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
   }

   public function getBlockPrefix()
   {
       return 'app_user_registration';
   }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults([
           'data_class' => Client::class,
       ]);
   }
}
```

But this give me a error

```
Neither the property "email" nor one of the methods "getEmail()", "email()", "isEmail()", "hasEmail()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Client".
```

Comment: That error is very clear, isn't it? Check your Client class.

Comment: Thx for comment, and yes, its clear but i want to take email field from my User class, not client

Comment: What if you remove all fields but 'user' from your ClientForm?

Comment: When i remove all field except user, the error was the same, but if i set date_class to NULL i have this 'Cannot read index "email" from object of type "AppBundle\Entity\Client" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.'

Comment: Oki, becuse earlier i've try a lot of different way to do this, i just delete getParent and getBlockPrefix from my ClientForm class and all look fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Oki, becuse earlier i've try a lot of different way to do this, i just delete getParent and getBlockPrefix from my ClientForm class and all look fine :)